# Facebook SSL certificates for social Plugins?

Tags: facebook, ssl-certificate

FB Documentation says that SSL certificates shall me mandatory for Canvas Apps.
Is it also mandatory for FB Social Plugins e.g. Like, Share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.
It's required only for Facebook Apps.

Comment: Thanks, my application uses FB for intial login creation and then uses the access_token for performing future actions. I guess it should not be mandatory for me to buy a SSL certificate, Right

Comment: Right now the SSL certificate is only required for apps running inside a Facebook iframe. I assume you have a web application run on your site so in this case you are safe for now

Comment: Yeah i was thinking on same lines. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Social Plugins will screws up if you share media content on your page like video, flash or Audio. It will not play anymore on the wall where it shard.
Media can only shared if your Blog Webpage works with SSL .